# Facebook FQL does not find photo privacy for photos on wall album

Tags: facebook-fql

I am trying to get the privacy values (from privacy table) for photos that are on the Wall Album. For photos on a Wall album, the privacy can be set independently for each photo (which is not the case for other albums).

The following query returns empty for all wall photos:

```
select id, value from privacy where id=<photo_id_here>
```

Does anyone else have this problem? I have been granted all permissions before trying this query on Graph API Explorer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hope you follow your post..

use the object_id instead of pid and id. its done

Comment: thanks karman. using object_id of the photo instead of pid worked!    "select id, value from privacy where id=<object_id_of_photo_here>"